# Create new renamed dataframes based on subset of current dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm working with approximately 400 dataframes so I need this to be able to be completed in a loop-like process.

I want to create a copy of all of my dataframes by selecting a subset of rows based on the time points, I can manually do this one at a time but can't figure out how to loop it. All of my dataframes are currently in a list together. Ideally I'd like the new dataframes to be renamed by adding a small string to the original name, i.e. df is the original and df_t is the subset that's been created. It'd also be really helpful if it's possible to put all of these dataframe copies into a list together.

My current code that works for a single dataframe:

```
df_t <- with(df, df[hour(columnname) > 5 | hour(columnname) <20,])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same code which works for one dataframe on a list of dataframes inside `lapply`. Assuming your list where all the dataframes are stored is called `list_df`

```
library(lubridate)
out <- lapply(mget(list_df), function(df) subset(df, hour(columnname) > 5 | hour(columnname) <20))
```

If you want to name each dataframe in the list you can do

```
names(out) <- paste0("df_t", seq_along(out))
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but unfortunately I'm getting an error `Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'`
Which strikes me as me column not being read as a date_time variable in the loop but they definitely are

Comment: @mgmcl95 You probably need `hour(columnname) > 5` and not `< 5` as in your attempt. I have updated the answer, can you check now ?

Comment: I realised my argument is above wrong and I actually want `hour(columnname) < 5 | hour(columnname) >20` I'll update that to reflect it, but swapping from `with` to `subset` it's now unable to find my column no matter what I do. Previously in `lapply` functions I've used the statement `df <- get(df)` within them if that helps?

Comment: @mgmcl95 Do you have only name of your dataframe in the list ? In that case, try `lapply(mget(list_df), function(df) subset(df, hour(columnname) < 5 | hour(columnname) <20))` It should also work with `with`.

Comment: That has worked, thank you! Sorry, I'm reasonably new to R